# How can I filter out the AC component of the output of a BQ51050B?

Tags: capacitor, filter, wireless, charging

After following the design recommendations mentioned in the datasheet by placing two capacitors in parallel, of 10u and 0.1u, there still is a relatively high AC component in the output signal (pin BAT) of a [BQ51050B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51050b.pdf). How could I filter it out even more?

Comment: AC component as in mains frequency? Please show with an oscillogram.